# Load element in other Database (Hibernate/Jpa/Spring)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I dont know how to explain my problem bcause i'm dont know speak english but i'm going to try..Sorry in advance for all fault

I build a website of a game server with Spring/Hibnate & JPA..

All is good, but i dont know how to load element in other database...

Look :

I have a 3 tables -> Accounts/Players/Servers

Servers has 3 columns : id/key/database

Database represent the database where is stocked all data of this servers

I would like to connect to this database to load some elements

Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.graviton.model");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(new Properties() {{
        put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", true);
    }});

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

My Server class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "servers")
public class Server {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private byte id;

    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "database")
    private String database;

}
```

You see i have a var "database" and i want to, with a service, connect to this database

```
@Service("serverService")
public class ServerServiceImpl implements ServerService {
@Autowired
private ServerRepository serverRepository;

@Override
@Cacheable("server")
public List<Server> findAll() {
    return serverRepository.findAll().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Server::getId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Thank you very mouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need entity manager to retrieve or load data into the database.
You have already created entity manager factory. Now from this factory you will get entity manager.
use this entity manager to perform operations on the DB.

Check out this tutorial it may help you:

https://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started?responseToken=abcc8885c19b3894f5318e82b29345f8

Comment: Hello thanks you, i have read, but i dont have find where i can execute query from other database.. i have my EntityFactory 
     entityManagerFactory.getObject(),   and after that he propose only to execute query on actual database